# How to get the estimated diagonal of Fisher Information Matrix from Adam optimizer in Keras/Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am implementing a regularization technique for reducing catastrophic forgetting of neural networks. I want to get the estimated diagonal of the Fisher Information Matrix of the model to calculate a regularization term. I have checked implementations of a similar method, Elastic Weight Consolidation. However, they only work on small models rather than large Keras models. I am thinking about a hack to make it faster and scalable.

Adam optimizer can estimate the diagonal of the Fisher Information Matrix of the model as in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6980.pdf). In Keras/TensorFlow, the `get_updates` method of the Adam optimizer calculates the diagonal `v_t` and returns the gradient updates. I am thinking of rewriting the method to directly add the regularization into the optimizer. Does it sound workable? Otherwise, should I implement it in the computational graph instead?

```
class Adam(Optimizer):
    """Adam optimizer.
    Default parameters follow those provided in the original paper.
    # Arguments
        learning_rate: float >= 0. Learning rate.
        beta_1: float, 0 < beta < 1. Generally close to 1.
        beta_2: float, 0 < beta < 1. Generally close to 1.
        amsgrad: boolean. Whether to apply the AMSGrad variant of this
            algorithm from the paper "On the Convergence of Adam and
            Beyond".
    # References
        - [Adam - A Method for Stochastic Optimization](
           https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980v8)
        - [On the Convergence of Adam and Beyond](
           https://openreview.net/forum?id=ryQu7f-RZ)
    """

    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999,
                 amsgrad=False, **kwargs):
        self.initial_decay = kwargs.pop('decay', 0.0)
        self.epsilon = kwargs.pop('epsilon', K.epsilon())
        learning_rate = kwargs.pop('lr', learning_rate)
        super(Adam, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with K.name_scope(self.__class__.__name__):
            self.iterations = K.variable(0, dtype='int64', name='iterations')
            self.learning_rate = K.variable(learning_rate, name='learning_rate')
            self.beta_1 = K.variable(beta_1, name='beta_1')
            self.beta_2 = K.variable(beta_2, name='beta_2')
            self.decay = K.variable(self.initial_decay, name='decay')
        self.amsgrad = amsgrad

    @interfaces.legacy_get_updates_support
    @K.symbolic
    def get_updates(self, loss, params):
        grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
        self.updates = [K.update_add(self.iterations, 1)]

        lr = self.learning_rate
        if self.initial_decay > 0:
            lr = lr * (1. / (1. + self.decay * K.cast(self.iterations,
                                                      K.dtype(self.decay))))

        t = K.cast(self.iterations, K.floatx()) + 1
        lr_t = lr * (K.sqrt(1. - K.pow(self.beta_2, t)) /
                     (1. - K.pow(self.beta_1, t)))

        ms = [K.zeros(K.int_shape(p),
              dtype=K.dtype(p),
              name='m_' + str(i))
              for (i, p) in enumerate(params)]
        vs = [K.zeros(K.int_shape(p),
              dtype=K.dtype(p),
              name='v_' + str(i))
              for (i, p) in enumerate(params)]

        if self.amsgrad:
            vhats = [K.zeros(K.int_shape(p),
                     dtype=K.dtype(p),
                     name='vhat_' + str(i))
                     for (i, p) in enumerate(params)]
        else:
            vhats = [K.zeros(1, name='vhat_' + str(i))
                     for i in range(len(params))]
        self.weights = [self.iterations] + ms + vs + vhats

        for p, g, m, v, vhat in zip(params, grads, ms, vs, vhats):
            m_t = (self.beta_1 * m) + (1. - self.beta_1) * g
            v_t = (self.beta_2 * v) + (1. - self.beta_2) * K.square(g)
            if self.amsgrad:
                vhat_t = K.maximum(vhat, v_t)
                p_t = p - lr_t * m_t / (K.sqrt(vhat_t) + self.epsilon)
                self.updates.append(K.update(vhat, vhat_t))
            else:
                p_t = p - lr_t * m_t / (K.sqrt(v_t) + self.epsilon)

            self.updates.append(K.update(m, m_t))
            self.updates.append(K.update(v, v_t))
            new_p = p_t

            # Apply constraints.
            if getattr(p, 'constraint', None) is not None:
                new_p = p.constraint(new_p)

            self.updates.append(K.update(p, new_p))
        return self.updates

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'learning_rate': float(K.get_value(self.learning_rate)),
                  'beta_1': float(K.get_value(self.beta_1)),
                  'beta_2': float(K.get_value(self.beta_2)),
                  'decay': float(K.get_value(self.decay)),
                  'epsilon': self.epsilon,
                  'amsgrad': self.amsgrad}
        base_config = super(Adam, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```